# What is causing these #1009 errors and how can I fix them

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flash

If anyone could help or give me some direction in fixing these errors, give me any tips, or recommend a better way to learn AS3 I would greatly appreciate it.

I have a main AS3 file: (I have the the imports all on separate lines but for some reason the site puts them all in one line.)

Main class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent

    public class DocumentMainNew extends MovieClip
    {
        public function DocumentMainNew():void
        {
            var angela:Hero = new Hero();
            var worm1:Enemy = new Enemy();
            angela.health = 100;
            angela.mana = 100;

            stage.focus = stage;
        }
    }
}
```

Hero class:

```
package 
{

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Hero extends MovieClip
    {
        //Objects
        public var angela:Hero;
        public var startMarker:StartMarker;
        public var boundaries:Boundaries;
        public var up:Up;
        public var powerUp:PowerUp;
        public var enemy:Enemy;

        //Regular vars
        public var health:Number;
        public var mana:Number
        private var vx:Number;
        private var vy:Number;
        private var jumps:Number;
        private var allowJump:Boolean;
        private var collision:Boolean;

        public function Hero()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

            up.visible = false;
            startMarker.visible = false;
        }

        public function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            //Gravitates the player
            vy += 2;

            //Moves the player
            angela.x += vx;
            angela.y += vy;
            //processes collisions 
            processCollisions();
            //scrolls the stage
            scrollStage();
        }
        public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37: //left arrow
                    vx = -7;
                    break;
                case 39: //right arrow
                    vx = 7;
                    break;
                case 38: //up arrow
                    if(jumps < 1)
                    {
                        if(allowJump) 
                        {
                            vy = -20;
                            jumps++;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
        public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:
                    vx = 0;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    vx = 0;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    break;
                default: 
                    break;
            }
        }
        public function processCollisions():void
        {
            //detects when player is falling
            if(vy > 0)
            {
                //respawns the player if they fell of the stage
                if(angela.y > stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    angela.x = startMarker.x;
                    angela.y = startMarker.y;
                    boundaries.x = 0;
                    boundaries.y = 0;
                    vy = 0;
                    jumps = 0;
                }
                //otherwise, processes collisions with boundaries
                else
                {
                    collision = false;
                    if(boundaries.hitTestPoint(angela.x, angela.y, true))
                    {
                        collision = true;
                        allowJump = true;
                        jumps = 0;
                    }
                    if (collision)
                    {
                        while (collision)
                        {
                            angela.y -= 0.1;
                            collision = false;
                        }
                        if(boundaries.hitTestPoint(angela.x,angela.y,true))
                        {
                            collision = true;
                        }
                        vy = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public function scrollStage():void
        {
            boundaries.x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - angela.x;
            angela.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            enemy.x = boundaries.x + 30;
            powerUp.x = boundaries.x - 200; 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors: (couldn't type the errors because for some reason it would mark the post as improperly formatted)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICET5.png) 
Thank you for any help. Once again I'm really sorry if this is a bad question I've tried finding the answers to this issue but haven't been able to fix any of them or find any explanation of how i should be using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the debugging (menu File -> Publish Settings -> SWF -> Permit Debugging) to learn the exact line that gives you the trouble.

Then, I'm quite sure it's the **stage** that is not accessible in the **Hero** constructor because **stage** is available only to objects attached to the display list. You need:

- to attach the **Hero** instance to **stage**
- to catch that moment inside the **Hero**

I think this will work. Main class:

```
var angela:Hero = new Hero;
addChild(angela);
```

Hero class:

```
public function Hero()
{
    super();

    // If stage is available, go straight to initializer.
    // Otherwise subscribe and wait for the stage to get available.
    if (stage) onStage(null);
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
}

private function onStage(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

    up.visible = false;
    startMarker.visible = false;
}
```